# Why doesn't Terraria show up in the 'My Games' folder?

Tags: terraria

Terraria seems to be working fine, but when I try to install a world or a mod, I'm told to go to the 'My Games' folder. However when I look under 'My Documents\My Games\', the Terraria folder is not there.

I don't know why and I haven't done anything to it. I have tried to look for it elsewhere but I still can't find it. How can I get the Terraria folder to appear in the 'My Games' folder?

Comment: exactly where are you looking?

Comment: That folder is in your documents.

Comment: @Chippies Unless he got it on steam.

Comment: Nope. The Steam version also saves to the `My Games` folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Terraria on Steam, it's important to check if you have one of your worlds saved in the cloud.

If it's not in the cloud, the `players` and `worlds` folders are located in `My Documents/My Games/Terraria`. If it is in the cloud, the `players` and `worlds` folders are located in `C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/userdata/{user_id}/105600/remote`, where `{user_id}` is your Steam ID's folder number. `C:/` is of course the drive where you have installed Terraria to.

Comment: Terraria does not differentiate between single-player and multi-player worlds at all. I believe those folders refer to local worlds and worlds in the cloud, respectively

Comment: That would make a lot more sense. Editing my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have at least one character and at least one world created and saved locally. Terraria does not create the folder in question until it needs to, which is upon saving a character or world on your local machine.

Comment: how do i save characters and worlds locally?

Comment: Creating a character and generating a new world on single player should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had a massive problem finding my characters and worlds after the 'My Games' folder completely vanished. I am using a Mac, and I found them  in Library, Application Support, Terraria.