# I have different characters in my "My Games/Terraria/Players Folder" than in my game itself

Tags: steam, terraria

I uninstalled Terraria because it kept crashing, after reinstallation, I opened it up, but both my characters and worlds were gone. They were still in my C:/documents/my games/terraria/worlds and /players folders. But I could not find them in my game. When I try to download a custom map, I can put it inside the worlds folder, but when I open Terraria, it does not show up. Someone please help me :C

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/228277/why-doesnt-terraria-show-up-in-the-my-games-folder), apparently the worlds/players can be located in C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/userdata/{user_id}/105600/remote